# Raspberry Pi QR Scanner high cpu usage

Tags: node.js, opencv, raspberry-pi, qr-code

I am trying to implement a QR scanning application on a Raspberry Pi using nodejs. The application is supposed to run in the background and upload QR codes to a database. I am able to get the basic QR recognizing functionality working with the following code:

```
const cv = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs')
const jsqr = require('jsqr')
const PNG = require('pngjs').PNG

const FPS = 10
const wCap = new cv.VideoCapture(0)
wCap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 600)
wCap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600)

setInterval(() => {
    const frame = wCap.read()
    const img = cv.imencode('.png', frame)    
    const png = PNG.sync.read(img)
    const code = jsqr(png.data, png.width, png.height)

    if (code) {
        console.log(`QR Code: ${code.data}`)
    } else {
        console.log('No code found.')
    }

}, 1000/FPS)
```

However the CPU usage is 80% and above on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 4GB RAM and an USB camera. I've also tried using `fswebcam` but it's really slow in capturing a picture.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve the CPU usage with another library for video capture.

Edit: `opnecv4nodejs` allows for easy conversion to `Uint8ClampedArray`, which reduces the CPU usage from the image conversion, however the process of video capture looks intensive for the RPi's USB camera. Increasing the interval brings down the CPU load and overheating.

```
setInterval(() => {
const frame = wCap.read()
const bgraArray = frame.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA).getData()
const clampedData = new Uint8ClampedArray(bgraArray)
const code = jsqr(clampedData, 640, 480)

if (code) {
    console.log(`QR Code: ${code.data}`)
} else {
    console.log('No code found')
}
}, 5000)
```

Update: The QR processing was moved to a worker thread and that made the application more responsive.

```
function getQR(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const worker = new Worker('./src/qr_decoder.js', { workerData: data })
        worker.on('message', (qrCode) => resolve(qrCode));
        worker.on('error', (error) =>  reject(error));
    })
}
```

The `qr_decoder.js` file:

```
const jsqr = require('jsqr')
const { workerData, parentPort, isMainThread } = require('worker_threads')

if (!isMainThread) {
    try {
        const qrCode = jsqr(workerData, 1280, 720)
        if (qrCode) {
            parentPort.postMessage(qrCode)
        } else {
            parentPort.postMessage(undefined)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: image encoding is expensive. Can you try reduction to capturing only and measure cpu usage again?

Comment: I removed all encoding and the cpu usage fell to 25-30%

Comment: do you need lossless compression? Raspberry Pi probably has hardware accelerated jpeg compression. Maybe other accelerated compression algorithms, too. But don't ask me how to use them in Python ;)

Comment: It seems you are not using multithreading. Have you tried to run the QR decoding part in a worker thread to reduce the CPU usage?